# Typescript keyof return array of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Test { 
  propA;
  propB;
  propC;
}
```

I want to create a method that returns an array of strings and type it to be only the keys existing in the Test class, how can I do this with the `keyof` feature?

```
 class Test { 
      propA;
      propB;
      propC;

   getSomeKeys() : keyof Test[] {
     return ['propA', 'propC']
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to wrap the `keyof Test` in brackets:

```
 class Test { 
   //...
   getSomeKeys() : (keyof Test)[] {
     return ['propA', 'propC']
   }
 }
```

Note though, that keyof also includes getSomeKeys in this case.

Comment: To solve the problem you've pointed out you can create a own filter like that `type Filter<K extends keyof Test> = K extends "getSomeKeys" | "anotherMethodToFilter" ? never : K` and then use it like so `Array<Filter<keyof Test>>` [TypeScript playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/AQYwNghgzlwCoFMoBdgG9gFgBQw-4AcAnAewIEFgBeYAcgloG4d9DSCAha4ARmd1bBiZAMLcA2rVoBdfi2ABzBMgDKJALYIA0ggCeUABQBKYAC5g5IkQi6APADEAlmGQIitgNZ6SAM3hJkAD5A9Hk8ImUAVyIAO2BJYQpaABo6RJEZeQBfHBzsHGRdAgRgJxc3Wy1gBAAPVxiAE1gvXV9-FBCaKtr6puAAIiVVDW09KH7gAB8BiBiSZAALNwBZZQWSBrgSMtciCYB+YBiEADc3M2AtIA)

Comment: True, but nowadays there's a builtin type for that: `Exclude<keyof Test, "getSomeKeys">`

Answer (score 23):

Use `Array<keyof Test>`:

```js
class Test {
    propA;
    propB;
    propC;

    getSomeKeys(): Array<keyof Test> {
        return ['propC'];
    }
}
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propA%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propC%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getSomeKeys()%3A%20Array%3Ckeyof%20Test%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B'propC'%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)